# Unable to find difference between two datetime variable

Tags: python, datetime

i am trying to find difference of two datetime variable in python

i tried using direct difference of two variables, tried using strptime() function

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now()
#timestamp variable gets time value from database
print "time 1:" + str(timestamp)
print "time 2:" + str(time)
#diff = timestamp-time; #already tried
#diff = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strtime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # already tried
diff= datetime.datetime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.datetime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print diff
```

Expect the output in seconds and actual result is type error

Comment: what is the type of `time` and `timestamp` respectively and what is the result of the print statement

Comment: *Edit your question* and provide actual values for `timestamp` and `time` and what your expected vs. actual result is.  That makes it a [mcve] so we don't have to guess.

Comment: time is time variable and timestamp is variable which has timestamp value from database ` now = datetime.datetime.now() time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") `

Comment: **Edit your question**.  Your code as it stands gives `name 'timestamp' is not defined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `total_seconds()` on `datetime.timedelta` to get difference in seconds:

```
diff = (timestamp-time).total_seconds()
```

**Code**:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = '2019-04-01 07:12:00'
time = '2019-04-01 07:11:0'

print("time 1:" + str(timestamp))
print("time 2:" + str(time))

timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

diff = (timestamp-time).total_seconds()

print(diff)
# 60.0
```

Comment: tried the above code error
Error Line: time = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Use this import line at the top: `from datetime import datetime`. The easiest way is just copy-paste my whole code and try.